# Encoding url's the Play! Framework

Tags: url-routing, urlencode, playframework

Is there a way to make the [Play! Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) ignore slashes and `?` in parts of the URL?

Typically, if I have the following:

`www.123.com/api/link/http:www.bla.com/?contenId=123&User=test`

It won't work. In that case, what I would want to do is simply have the link in the last part of the URL in a `String` variable to save it. I suppose I can force the client to replace the `/` and `?` by something else, but I would rather keep it simple.

My first thought was that maybe there is a way to configure the routing such that we have something like:

`/api/link/{data}`

where `data` would hold whatever remains of the URL. Can't find out how to do that though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have `:` `/` `?` except your main URL. You should **encode** your parameter to append it to main URL. See [URLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) for Java.

This is not a valid URL:

```
http://www.123.com/api/link/http://www.bla.com/?contenId=123&User=test
```

It must be:

```
http://www.123.com/api/link/http%3a%2f%2fwww.bla.com%2f%3fcontenId%3d123%26User%3dtest
```

Then you can pass it to `{data}` parameter and **decode** it in your handler method.

Comment: +1, because if the ? in the URL is part of the text, rather than marking off the query string, then it *must* be escaped.